# How can I access a struct field within the "new" associated function?

Tags: rust, struct

I am trying to create a "constructor" for a struct through an associated function called `new`. In this "constructor" I need to access one of the fields of the struct that I have already defined/instantiated (within the "constructor"). The public key NEEDS to be derived from the private key aka the second field in the struct is derived from the first field. Is this possible in Rust? Or is there a different pattern I should be trying?

One thought was that I could pass the private key in as an argument to the "constructor", but I don't think this satisfies my goals for this specific case. I think upon creation the struct itself should generate the random entropy `&mut OsRng` rather than it be passed in by the calling method.

Also passing `&mut self` to the "constructor" does not work either because upon instantiation there is no "self" to pass into the `Wallet::new()` function.

Ex Code.

```
use k256::{SecretKey, elliptic_curve::PublicKey};
pub struct Wallet {
    private_key: SecretKey<Secp256k1>,
    public_key: PublicKey<Secp256k1>,
}

impl Wallet {

    pub fn new() -> Wallet {
        Wallet {
            private_key: SecretKey::random(&mut OsRng),
            public_key: self.private_key.public_key(),  // <- This is where the error occurs, there is no
                                                        // "self" object to access and just using 
                                                        // "private_key.public_key()" leads to the error:
                                                        // "cannot find the value private_key in this scope"
        }
    }
}
```

Instantiating a `Wallet` object:

```
let wallet: Wallet = Wallet::new();
```

Comment: Where do the types `SecretKey`, `PublicKey`, and `Secp256k1` come from?

Comment: They are imported from the k256 crate I will add the use imports to the code. Those types aren't causing the issue necessarily, the main point, is that I am trying to use a previously initialized field within the struct initialization that the compiler is complaining about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to access `self`:

```
pub struct Wallet {
    private_key: SecretKey<Secp256k1>,
    public_key: PublicKey<Secp256k1>,
}

impl Wallet {
    pub fn new() -> Wallet {
        let private_key = SecretKey::random(&mut OsRng);
        let public_key = private_key.public_key();

        Wallet {
            private_key: private_key,
            public_key: public_key,
        }
    }
}
```

**But you have to take care of the ownership of the `private_key`.** If calling to `private_key.public_key()` moves the ownership of the `private_key`, the above code will not compile. That is, if the `public_key()` method is defined as:

```
impl SecretKey {
    pub fn public_key(self) -> PublicKey {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then calling `private_key.public_key()` moves the ownership of `private_key`, and the code cannot compile.

If the `public_key()` method is defined as:

```
impl SecretKey {
    pub fn public_key(&self) -> PublicKey {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then calling to `private_key.public_key()` doesn't move the ownership of `private_key`, and the code can compile.

Comment: This worked! Like you mention the function `public_key()` implemented within SecretKey accepts a `&self` argument so this compiled. Thanks

Comment: As followup, is it possible to access other associated methods within that `new` method since there is no &self reference passed into it?
I.E.

`let address = some_other_wallet_method();`

Is calling this within `Wallet::new()` possible?

Comment: Associated functions are just like normal static class methods in other languages. We can use `Self::other_associated_function()` in the `Wallet::new`. If you want to access the same `Wallet` object in other associated functions, you have to pass it as argument. If you don't want to expose `other_associated_function`, you can just remove the `pub` keyword.

Comment: BTW, the `Wallet::new()` is called **associated function**: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-functions-and-methods

Comment: Thanks for the vocabulary clarification and answer to the follow up question